# External Hard Disk is not being detected after recent upgrade

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive

I am using Arch Linux and I recently upgraded my machine's kernel to the latest one. `Linux 6.2.12-arch1-1` if it matters.

Ever since then my machine is not able to detect the external HDD. I have 2 external HDDs. 1 with BTRFS and the other with EXT4 both aren't getting detected. I tried using Mouse / keynboard and they work fine.

Here's the dmesg after connecting the HDD with BTRFS:

```
[34765.295989] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [VRTC] (00000000b13b9934) [SystemCMOS] (20221020/evregion-130)
[34765.296027] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20221020/exfldio-261)
[34765.296065] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q9A due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20221020/psparse-529)
[34841.022047] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[34841.040628] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25ee, bcdDevice=110..42
[34841.040657] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[34841.040669] usb 4-2: Product: My Book 25ED
[34841.040677] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[34841.040685] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: [redacted]
[34916.397971] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 10
[37705.154806] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[37705.173409] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25ee, bcdDevice=110.42
[37705.173437] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[37705.173450] usb 4-2: Product: My Book 25ED
[37705.173458] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[37705.173466] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: [redacted]
[37941.803264] perf: interrupt took too long (5174 > 5142), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 38400
```

I thought it might the disks but I tried connecting both hard disk to a different computer and they work fine. Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Installing a new OS usually will not wreck external disks. The connection (logical) path between the system and the device contains the problem. What does `lsusb`and `lsblk` tell you. — Please update your question by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"VRTC" in the message relates to Intel Virtual Real-Time Configuration
Manager.
It may mean the your BIOS/UEFI firmware exposes a dummy RTC device that
with which the setup has a problem.

The mention of `SystemCMOS` in the message might mean a problem with the
CMOS battery. If that's the case, it may need to be replaced,
especially if this computer is not new.

This could possibly point to a problem with the BIOS/UEFI.
I would advise to install the latest version, even if it's already
installed (to refresh).

Other advice that worked for some people is to add `acpi=off` to the
kernel boot command (BOOT_IMAGE).

It's also possible that the ACPI Error messages are not the cause of
the problem. In that case, the simplest solution would be to undo the
latest update to the Arch Linux kernel and skip this kernel version.
If this fixes the problem, you should signal it to the developers
in the Arch Linux forums.

Comment: So, it turned out that I forgot to reboot to load the new kernel after updating. I just did a reboot and it is now working. Thank you for the help. really appreciate it!